# How to create Rx observable for some specific non DOM events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I would like to handle some events triggered by a user. And I would like to do that with RxJS Observables.

In my case a user can register a function in the console of the browser like this

```
window.barfoo.register((bar, foo) => {
    console.log('foo=' + foo + ' bar=' + bar)'
});
```

Now, to attach the registration to a stream I can wrap the registration code like this

```
register$ = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    window.barfoo.register = (callback) => {
        observer.next(callback);
    };
});
```

I have my doubts about this code, so I'm wondering if this is the proper way to solve this? The reason for that is, I have to create the function inside the `Observable.create` callback. Which in my case is a problem. Because  `window.barfoo.register` is created first (and I cannot change that) before I can create the observable.

```
window.barfoo = {
    register: (cb) => { /* store cb somewhere and trigger something */    
};

register$ = Rx.Observable.create(......????.....);
```

Note: although I cannot change the order of things, I can change the implementation of `register`!

Any suggestions how to setup the observable ?

Comment: So you want to override the `window.barfoo.register` function with `(callback) => {...}`?

Comment: Yes I could replace the register function, meaning my first code example would work. But is that best solution. I know that Observable is millions of operators, so maybe there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS 5 has static constructors to create Observables from different types of events but I think your use-case is different. I was thinking about [`bindCallback()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) but that's probably not what you can use if I understand your use-case correctly.

It looks like you'll need to use multicasting for this because otherwise you could override the function multiple times and then only the latest observer will receive any values (note the `share()` operator at the end).

```
var register$ = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    let oldRegister = window.barfoo.register;
    window.barfoo.register = (callback) => {
        observer.next(callback);
    };

    return () => {
        window.barfoo.register = oldRegister;
    };
}).share();
```

Also it's probably a good idea to return a teardown function that registers the original function back.

Comment: `share` is indeed important here! thnx `bindCallback` sounds interesting, maybe I can somehow use it. In your example code you return a value from within `Observable.create`, as far as I understand that is not possible, right?

Comment: It is. If you return a function from the callback in `Observable.create` it's going to be called when unsubscribing. See https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md

Comment: Or maybe simply `Rx.Subject`

Comment: Actually, a `Subject` isn't ideal for this because than you'd have to do `window.barfoo.register = oldRegister` manually. When you return the teardown function you can be sure it'll be called when both the source completes or you unsubscribe.